# How to design layout in filemaker

Tags: filemaker

I want to design the following layout in filemaker. I am a newbie to filemaker and am confused how to design it.Can anyone help me?
Is this a portal or list i am confused?
[image: I want to design this layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need portals and therefore relationships on which this portals to be based on.

This question is too broad and not realy programming question. You are much better off going to a dedicated FileMaker forum which is better suited to help beginners.

Another alternative would be doing some basic training in FileMaker development.

Comment: You can download the ebook FileMaker Training Series for version 15. It’s free, and although it’s not for the latest version it should get you a long way. http://info2.filemaker.com/FTS-Basics-15.html